# Losing session Variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been researching this issue and trying to find a fix for this. When I create my session variables and then do a response.redirect(), im losing my session variable. Does anyone have a fix for this. I have tried the following and still no success.

```
response.redirect("site", false)
server.transfer("site")
```

**Edit**

Here is my code:

```
Session("Config") = drop_config.SelectedValue
Session("Weight") = radOutput.SelectedValue
Session("QNHUnits") = radQNH.SelectedValue

Response.Redirect("test.aspx")
```

Note: I seeing that this only happens in IE not Fire Fox

Comment: how did u create session variable? please show us some of your code

Comment: So if you were to create a session, response.redirect to another page, and check that session, it would be gone? or are you doing anything else?

Comment: Sounds like your session cookies are being wiped out.

Comment: What are the items you had set for **drop_config**, **radOutput**, & **radQNH**?  You can just add items, but not values, thus the Session variables might be set to null.  Also, if you set a break point on Response.Redirect, do your session variable have values at that point?

Comment: I assume the page you are redirecting to is in the same application as the one you are coming from and that you are not switching from http to https or anything?

Comment: the items that im adding to the session as just strings like "test". To answer your question Mark, when I set break points they do have values. When I run locally it works fine, but when I put it on the server, I getting an error saying null values which tells me that the session values are getting lost

Comment: Hi Chris, yes im redirecting to a page in the solution

Comment: Is this in an Iframe? Could be a cookie/security problem in IE. I've seen this.

Comment: No its no iframe or anything complicated